# My combobox (populated through Ajax) fails if too much data

Tags: xml, ajax, jsp

I am using Oracle SQL, JSP, XML

I have a few comboboxes which are populated in the following way:

- Ajax runs an Oracle Query, and creates XML from it.
- This XML is used to populate the combobox

I create one XML for all the comboboxes together.

The last combobox fails sometimes if there are too many entries in the combobox.  When I say too many entries I mean more than five or six!

A workaround is to limit the size of the entries in the query to say 10 characters.

However I would like to solve the problem.  I have a feeling that there is some limit to the XML string size, and that that is causing me the problem.  I do not know though where this is held though.  At the end of the day I am talking about a few thousand bytes! not 4MB or anything like that, so I am a little surprised.

The code I use to call the XML is as follows:

```
var xmlURL = "test_xml.jsp";
var xmlCurr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlCurr.async = "false";
xmlCurr.load(xmlURL);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have answered my question.

It was nothing to do with the size of the XML.

Rather the SELECT query included an ampersand character in the results coming from the database. When I changed the ampersand to a '+' then everything worked!